# Passing Image between View Controllers using custom protocol and delegate

Tags: objective-c

I am a beginner in objective C. I want to pass an image from `ViewController` to `SecondClass` for showing the image in `SecondClass` which is already in `ViewController`. But the transfered `imageview` shows `null` value after transferring and I can't reach the `secondClass` after pressing the button. my code is below,

**myProtocol.h**

```
@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>

-(UIImage *)transferImage;

@end
```

**ViewController.h file**

```
#import "SecondClass.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<myProtocol, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

{

   UIView *view;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m file**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "SecondClass.h"

#import "myProtocol.h"

(void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"]];

     [view addSubview:imageView];

    NSLog(@"I am in VC.m");

}

-(UIImage *)transferImage{

    NSLog(@"I am in transferImage");

    return imageView.image;

}

- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender {

    SecondClass *secClass = [[SecondClass alloc]init]; 

    secClass.delegate=self;

    [secClass callTransfer];

    NSLog(@"I am in sender");

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secClass animated:YES];

}

@end
```

**SecondClass.h**

```
#import "myProtocol.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondClass : UIViewController<myProtocol,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

{
    UIView *secondView;

    IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;

    id <myProtocol> myDelegate;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *myImage;

@property(nonatomic,assign) id delegate;

-(void)callTransfer;

@end
```

**SecondClass.m**

```
#import "SecondClass.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

#import "myProtocol.h"

@implementation SecondClass

@synthesize delegate,myImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  [secondView addSubview:myImage];

}

-(void)callTransfer

{
    myImage.image=[delegate performSelector:@selector(transferImage)];

    myImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"];

    NSLog(@"%@",myImage.image);

    NSLog(@"I am in call transfer");

}

@end
```

Comment: I would have the same problem, as you have resolved?

"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339877/show-image-in-viewcontroller-when-button-is-clicked-in-secondviewcontroller"

Answer (score 1):

Use this code and check it

```
UIImage *img = [delegate performSelector:@selector(transferImage)]; 
NSLog(@"%@",img );
NSLog(@"I am in call transfer");
```

Comment: the transferImage function returns nill. I've Printed it in Log view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a delegate here you are massively overcomplicating the simple task of passing data to the new view controller.

```
SecondClass *secClass = [[SecondClass alloc] init]; 

secClass.myImage.image = imageView.image;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:secClass animated:YES];
```

### Update

You mentioned this is for practice - but it's still fundamentally wrong. A more normal case for a delegate would be to send the image from `child -> parent` not from the `parent -> child` as the parent owns the child and can just call methods without the elaborate protocol set up.

```
#import "ChildVC.h"

@interface ParentVC : UIViewController <ChildDelegate>

@end

@implementation ParentVC

- (void)pushViewController;
{
    ChildVC *childVC = [[ChildVC alloc] init];
    childVC.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childVC animated:YES];
}

- (void)childViewController:(ChildVC *)childViewController didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image;
{
    // do something with the image passed back
}

@end
```

and then the child will look like

```
@class ChildVC;

@protocol ChildDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)childViewController:(ChildVC *)childViewController didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image;

@end

@interface ChildVC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ChildDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

@end

@implementation ChildVC

- (void)whenSomethingInterestingHappens;
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(childViewController:didFinishWithImage:)]) {
        [self.delegate childViewController:self didFinishWithImage:self.image];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. I know. But I m trying to pass that image through my own protocol. I am practicing protocol and delegate so that I can use it in future.

Comment: @Mashrufee updated to show how you might really use in a real world scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
how to pass two view controller image for delegate method :



//step 1: create for delegate method :


@protocol DrawViewDelegate
-(void)didReceiveDrawImage:(UIImage *)DrawImage;
 @end

step2: delegate pass for your first view:

@interface EditorViewController :
 UIViewController< DrawViewDelegate >
```

// step3: your must be view controller pass view at time

```
like : crop.delegat=self;
```

//  step:4 pass second view controller protocol

```
@protocol DrawViewDelegate;
```

// step:5 use method set image pass other view:

```
[_delegate didReceiveDrawImage:savedimage];



//step: 6 get second view image to first view



-(void)didReceiveDrawImage:(UIImage *)DrawImage
```