# Show image in ViewController when button is clicked in SecondViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

How to show an `UIIimage` by clicking on an `UIButton` inside another `UIViewController`? I would like to add to the same `UIButton` the command to add an image to the SecondViewController. Excused my poor question.

**myProtocol.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>

-(UIImage *)transferImage;

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "SecondClass.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<myProtocol, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
    UIView *view;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "myProtocol.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"VoodooVibe@2x.png"]];
    [view addSubview:_imageView];
    NSLog(@"I am in VC.m");
}

-(UIImage *)transferImage{

    NSLog(@"I am in transferImage");
    return _imageView.image;
}

- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender {

    SecondViewController *secClass = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    secClass.delegate=self;    
    [secClass callTransfer];
    NSLog(@"I am in sender");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secClass animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myProtocol.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController :UIViewController
                                  <myProtocol,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UIView *secondView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
    id <myProtocol> myDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *myImage;
@property(nonatomic,assign) id delegate;

-(void)callTransfer;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "myProtocol.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize delegate,myImage;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [secondView addSubview:myImage]; 
}

-(void)callTransfer{

    myImage.image=[delegate performSelector:@selector(transferImage)];
    myImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"VoodooVibe@2x.png"];
    NSLog(@"%@",myImage.image);
    NSLog(@"I am in call transfer");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: if you insert so much code please look next time to format it. This way its much easier and faster to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates should normally be used, if you you have a class included inside your `UIViewController` which will do something and notify you with the delegate method when the specific process has finished. But in this case you would set an `UIImage` two times. Once by your `delegate` and a second time by setting an `UIImage` programmatically.

You shouldn't do anything like calling a method for initializing the `UIImage` of the second `UIViewController` from outside. Just call everything inside `viewDidLoad` and you don't have to care about it, because the `UIViewController` handles it itself.

You just have to insert an `UIImageView` inside your `SecondViewController` and connect it to your header file. then you can access it inside the m. file. I had the problem that I first used a `jpg` instead of a `png`, but after changing the suffix everything worked fine.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender {

    SecondViewController *secClass = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [secClass setImageName:@"pic.png"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secClass
                                         animated:YES];

}
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *imageName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m** (There are just these two lines)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]];
}
```

Comment: The method transfertImage would have to send an image to the SecondVieController...

Comment: I just created the snippets you would need to solve your problem. I also changed my answer above. Be careful with the `delegate`, you just use it in a wrong place. This is not a process you really need a delegate. A better use is if you have an asynchronous task and the delegates notifies you when the process has ended. This here is just a simple call with setting an `UIImage`.

Comment: Common, I posted the way it works. Compare your classes and look whats the difference to mine. Its about programming and its a basic problem. This is just the beginning so learn to read code. You won't learn anything if you already have a problem with this and can't compare it.

Comment: You asked this question and I also answered it hours ago. Have a look at it. If you post anything you always get notified about, so keep reading your posts if you write any!